# Hiding and fading in div on hover issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to hide a div on hover and then fadein a seperate div using jquery. 
I have multiple divs with the classes mentioned above, In a grid.

```
<div class="intro-service">Welcome, User1</div>
<div class="desc-service" style="display:none;">Hidden Div 1(Should show on hover)</div>

<div class="intro-service">Welcome, User2</div>
<div class="desc-service" style="display:none;">Hidden Div 2(Should show on hover)</div>

<div class="intro-service">Welcome, User3</div>
<div class="desc-service" style="display:none;">Hidden Div 3(Should show on hover)</div>
```

What I want to achieve is , When hovering over one of them , The hidden div relevant to the div will fadein.

```
$('.intro-service').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.intro-service').hide();
  $(this).find('.desc-service').fadeIn();
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.desc-service').hide();
  $(this).find('.intro-service').fadeIn();
});
```

How could I achieve this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `mouseover` event here because once you hide the div, `mouseleave` event wont be fired and the second part of your code wont execute. Use `mouseleave` on `desc-service` instead.

```js
$('.intro-service').mouseover(function() {
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).next('.desc-service').fadeIn();
});

$('.desc-service').mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).hide();
  $(this).prev('.intro-service').fadeIn();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="intro-service">Welcome, User1</div>
<div class="desc-service" style="display:none;">Hidden Div 1(Should show on hover)</div>

<div class="intro-service">Welcome, User2</div>
<div class="desc-service" style="display:none;">Hidden Div 2(Should show on hover)</div>

<div class="intro-service">Welcome, User3</div>
<div class="desc-service" style="display:none;">Hidden Div 3(Should show on hover)</div>
```

Comment: It works but, What is wrong with my code that makes it not work that way?

Comment: @IbrahimMaher you are using `$(this).find('.intro-service')` which will try to select elements with class `intro-service` in the descendants of `$(this)`(which is `intro-service`). You need only `$(this)` to hide. Similarly `$(this).find('.desc-service').fadeIn();` will try to search `desc-service` in the descendants of `$(this)`(which is `intro-service`). You need to search for siblings instead thats why I used `.next()`.

Comment: Also, using hover will not solve your purpose because once the element is hidden you cannot get `mouseleave` event on it. That is why I used separate `mouseleave` on `desc-service`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```js
$('.intro-service').hover(function() {
  $(this).hide(); // This will hide the div that is being hovered
  $(this).next('.desc-service').fadeIn(); // This will first get the next div with class desc-service and apply fadein effect over it
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="intro-service">Welcome, User1</div>
<div class="desc-service" style="display:none;">Hidden Div 1(Should show on hover)</div>

<div class="intro-service">Welcome, User2</div>
<div class="desc-service" style="display:none;">Hidden Div 2(Should show on hover)</div>

<div class="intro-service">Welcome, User3</div>
<div class="desc-service" style="display:none;">Hidden Div 3(Should show on hover)</div>
```

Comment: Works but, What's the issue with my code that's causing it not to work?